# Why does Azure ACS require authentication every time I debug my project?

Tags: acs

When your developing an Azure webrole in Visual Studio every time press F5 to run the project and wait for Azure development environment to start up and then I'm required to visit the login page and go through the Azure ACS authentication process.  What needs to be done to enable ACS authentication status to be persisted across compilation and debug sessions?

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the ACS token in the browser’s cookie and make it persist after the browser is closed. Then modify your service application so that it checks if the token in cookie is valid and has expired or not. Then decide whether you need to request user to sign in or not. Just make sure to validate the token every time.

BR,
Arwind

Comment: Thanks Arwind.  Are you aware of any sample code for this approach?

Comment: You can refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx for instruction on working with cookies in ASP.NET. You can take the same approach. Make sure to set the ACS token as the cookie’s content.